# Get custom posts with certain ids in a custom loop using a shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, shortcode

So I'm using custom loop and shortcode to insert it in any page.
Like this:

```
function register_custom_shortcode($atts){

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'ids' => '', // this is what I need
        ), $atts));

    $cutom_loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'cutom_post',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        ) );

    ob_start();


    while ( $cutom_loop->have_posts() ) : $cutom_loop->the_post(); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?>>

    // post thumb, title and so on

    </article>

    <?php endwhile;


    wp_reset_postdata();
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode( 'custom_loop', 'register_custom_shortcode' );
```

How shoud I handle this ids to have shortcode like this: `[custom_loop ids="112,93,34,91"]`?

**EDIT:**

Ok, if i add `'post__in' => array(189,173)` to new WP_Query it will output only this two posts, but still can't figure out how to grab this ids from shortcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use comma separated id's in the shortcode like `"112,93,34,91"`, you can make use of the [explode](http://php.net/explode) function to make an array out of the string, like the following:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'ids' => ''
), $atts));

$id_array = explode(',', $ids);
```

Then you just have to use `'post__in' => $id_array`

Comment: Is there a way to show all IDS if the $atts is not set? Right now I just have the if statement wrapped around the query args but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this? 

    if( isset( $atts['ids'] ) ) {
        $options = array(
            'post_type'         => 'webinars',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'post__in'          => $id_array,
        );
    } else {...}